# How to change text

Tags: python, django

In my Django admin I have a TabularInLine class. How can I change the text circled by red color on picture? [image]

Comment: What is your model declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python3

```
class Line(models.Model):
    # Your others model field Declaration
    field1 = models.CharField("Model Field", unique=True, max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.field1
        # or return "Any text that you want to show as model name"
```

In older version of Django and Python2 you will often see following function as well.

```
class Line(models.Model):
    # Your others model field Declaration
    field1 = models.CharField("Model Field", unique=True, max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.field1
        # or return "Any text that you want to show as model name"
```

**The following code will act as a Model name in entire project.**

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of doing this is to implement [`__str__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#str) method inside `Line`model class, like this:

```
class Line(models.Model):
    # Yourcode

    def __str__(self):
        return "Some text" # you can use any Line's field her e.g return self.name
```

Note this will change Line objects name on entire site, not only in `TabularInLine`